# Flexbox animations

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, flexbox

I want to animate my `flexbox` items when they `transform` from row to column while changing the size of browser window.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
div {   
    background-color : red;
    width:50px;
}
@media (max-width:500px) {
    body {
        flex-direction: column;     
    }
}
</style>
<body>
<div>
    <p>1st block</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>2nd block</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>3rd block</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>4th block</p>
</div>    
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Here I have 4 blocks  which I want to make it responsive but have some animations using `transition` property.
Please use `transition` and explain where can I put that part of code in here.

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it only with CSS — `flex-direction` is `not animatable` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction.

Check out list of CSS3 animatable properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties.